# CakePHP 3.6: join query

Tags: php, join, cakephp

I have the following tables:

```
customers[id, name, surname, phone, text, balance, created]

service_types[id, title, price, length, is_subscription, created, payment]

customer_service_types[id, customer_id, service_type_id, price, created]
```

And the relations:

**ServiceTypesTable.php:**

```
$this->hasMany('CustomerServiceTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'service_type_id'
    ]);
```

**CustomerServiceTypesTable.php:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Customers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('ServiceTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'service_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

This is my code right now:

```
    $customerServiceTypes = TableRegistry::get('CustomerServiceTypes');
    $customers_count = $customerServiceTypes->find()
        ->select(['customer_id'])
        ->distinct()
        ->where(['service_type_id <>' => 3])->count();
```

I want to modify it inorder to check in the `where` clause if `service_types.payment = 0` from the join of `customer_service_types` and `service_types` on

```
customer_service_types.service_type_id = service_types.id
```

Comment: Is `payment` really a column in `service_types`? Or in `customer_service_types`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt its a `service_types` column

Comment: Then you should be able to contain `ServiceTypes` in your query, and add `'ServiceTypes.payment' => 0` in your `where` clause.